# Video Player inside List SwiftUI iOS 16 - controls not displayed

Tags: swiftui-list, ios16

Caught a strange situation.
In the new version of iOS, the controls for the video player are not shown if the video player is placed inside the list.

In iOS 15.6.1 this code works fine as it should.

```swift
struct ContentView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack{
            List(0..<2) { i in
                VStack
                {
                   
                    let vp = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "http://wiu.ks-api.com/Content/file_3004.mp4")!)
                    
                    VideoPlayer(player: vp)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, idealHeight: 320)
                        .padding(.horizontal, -20)
                        .onDisappear{vp.pause()}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Same thing is happening in a TabView for me when setting `.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))`, if removed it works.

Answer (score 13):

You can add `.clipped()` modifier to `VideoPlayer()`
it works inside TabView `.tabViewStyle(.page)`

Comment: You deserve many claps. Thank you!

Comment: Had the same issue (typical SwiftUI nonsense). This solves it. Thank you

Comment: lol. It really works for me in case `TabView { VideoPlayer() }.tabViewStyle(.page)`